# Usb mass storage file system location on QNX

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

I need my software to be notifed that usb mass storage stick has been inserterd, also i need locationa where this stick has been mounted. Is it possible to obtain this information, especially location on fs where stick has been mounted from any C library ?

For instertion i already know usbd_connect() and i'm using it. Unfortunatelly there is no information with respect to location on fs.

regards
JosiP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

io-usb should be up and running on your target.

Add the library "usbdi" to your project.

Then use the following code snipet :

```
#include <sys/usbdi.h>

static struct usbd_connection *conn_usb = NULL;
static void cbinsert(struct usbd_connection *connection, usbd_device_instance_t *ins);
static void cbremove(struct usbd_connection *connection, usbd_device_instance_t *ins);

        int init(void)
        {
            usbd_funcs_t funcs = { _USBDI_NFUNCS, cbinsert, cbremove, NULL };
            usbd_connect_parm_t parm = {NULL, USB_VERSION, USBD_VERSION, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL,  &funcs,0};

            if (usbd_connect(&parm, &conn_usb) != EOK) {
                /* write your own error handler */
            }
```

And then, add your customized handler :

```
static void cbinsert(struct usbd_connection *usb_connection,usbd_device_instance_t *usb_instance)
{
    if (usb_instance->ident.dclass == 8 && usb_instance->ident.subclass == 6) {
        /* USB mass storage */
    } else if (usb_instance->ident.dclass == 3 && usb_instance->ident.subclass == 1) {
        /* USB mouse */
    } else {
        /* unknown device */
    }
```

This is an example. You will have to customized it.
But everything you need is there.

Hope this help !
Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

Try using MCD(Media Content Detector) in QNX. Refer to the below links -

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/m/mcd.html
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dev_pub.ref_guide%2Ftopic%2Fdrivers.html

Comment: If you know how to do it with this tool, then give the solution. Don't use answers to ask questions.

Comment: @Alex.S Changed the answer. I guess this is enough. I do not think spoon feeding is required here. The author can learn this and solve it himself.