# How to detect the path for usb in QNX

Tags: usb, qnx

How we can detect that USB (pen drive) is under which path?
For one of our issue device was connected to /dev/ttyUSB1 instead of /dev/ttyUSB0.

How we can detect that where device is connected? 
Is there any command i QNX so that we can use that to detect the path of usb?

Comment: USB mass storage should mount on /dev/usb* and not /dev/ttyUSB*. Please check the mcd.conf file. You will see the paths.

Comment: @Shaibal I can see that in ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 and in another device /dev/umass0t11. There is not /dev/usb* path.
which path can I see mcd.conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this thread. This will solve your problem I hope.

[Usb mass storage file system location on QNX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164829/usb-mass-storage-file-system-location-on-qnx/34410547#34410547)